# R crashing when using foreach doParallel and XML

Tags: xml, r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am writing a function that scrapes a huge XML file. Since the nodes are about one million I would like to use the foreach package. Code and relevat comment below

```
xmlfile=xmlParse(file="./DATI/xmldata.xml") #read the file

#explore
if(exists("dbfromxml")) rm(dbfromxml)


root<-xmlRoot(xmlfile)
persons<-xmlChildren(root)
rm(root)
nrecords<-xmlSize(persons)

#set out the parallel framework

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cores <- getOption("mc.cores", detectCores())
cl<-makeCluster(cores,outfile="ciao.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)
dbfromxml<-foreach(i=1:10,.combine=rbind,.packages = "XML") %dopar% {
personsxml<-persons[[i]]
processaXMLPersona(personsxml) #this function works properly ouside a do parallel environment
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

The problem arise when I set out the doParallel / makeCluster infrastructure loading .packages = "XML" that makes the R cluster crashing. The following errors come out: Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection; Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection

Comment: Where does `processaXMLPersona` come from? The error indicates you are trying to read/write to a connection in parallel.

Comment: Hi Roland processaXMLPersona  is a function that is loaded by source. It accepts and xmlobject.

Comment: Since running that function in parallel probably is your problem I don't see how we are expected to help you if you don't share that function.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the problem is that the XML package (via libxml2) uses pointers which are not valid in a new process started by foreach. This means to make it work you have to load / parse the XML document independently in each loop.